# Taxonomy path to a view instead to the taxonomy page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a Vocabulary taxonomy with some terms (alfa, beta,). This vocabulary is se to be sync with a menu (myMenu) using the taxonomy_menu module.

I need the path of the terms (the path of the menu items) to be products/[term:name] instead of taxonomy/[term:name].

'products' is the path of a view page and the **term name** will be taken as a argument.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TVI](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module should help you with this:

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding
>   of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.
>   Using TVI you can easily create custom views to output all terms in X
>   vocabuarly.

Comment: Actually, I've jsut read the question properly and it seems this might not be what you're after. Seems like you want Contextual Arguments in a view...

Comment: The idea is: the taxonomy generate the menu, then the menu items (the terms of the taxonomy) should have a path with the pattern: products/[term:name]. But can't set this value in the path of each term. I need to have this path pattern for each new term created in this vocabulary. In the other side I already created the view and it's working fine with the arguments